# Point cloud query is very slow and not using parrallel scan or more memory

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgpointcloud

The following PostGIS query is running very slow (> 1 day for about 1 million records):

```
UPDATE test.table1
    SET area= ST_Area(PC_EnvelopeGeometry(pa))
    WHERE area is null or area <> ST_Area(PC_EnvelopeGeometry(pa))::real
```

pa contains the point cloud patch (600 points)
I had created following indexes:

- spatial index (using Gist on PC_EnvelopeGeometry(pa)), binary index on area.

The PC has Core I7 processor, 64GB Ram with 1TB SSD & 4TB HDD. I've set the following Postgres server configuration:

```
shared_buffers = 13280MB, temp_buffers = 4096MB, work_mem = 2047MB, max_stack_depth = 3MB, 
min_parallel_table_scan_size = 5MB,
min_parallel_index_scan_size = 128kB
effective_cache_size = 18GB,
force_parallel_mode = on
```

Please advise what can be done to reduce the query processing time.